# Visual Leak Detector won't to start

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2015

I use visual leak detector in several projects under Visual Studio 2015.
I have integrated it to my new project but it doesn't work at all.
During starting debug mode in the Output Window I can see:

```
VLD: New allocation at already allocated address:
```

I can not see this message in other projects. If this prevent VLD of working what causing this message?

Answer (score 0):

From VLD source code  [vld.cpp](https://github.com/KindDragon/vld/blob/master/src/vld.cpp):

> A block with this address has already been allocated. The previously allocated block must have been freed (probably by some mechanism unknown to VLD), or the heap wouldn't have allocated it again. Replace the previously allocated info with the new info.

Comment: I saw this comment on GitHub but I don't understand it well. Does it mean other project running VLD is blocking this one?

Comment: in my understanding,that means the library(VLD) think a memory(address) was allocated twice(at least),this is not right,however the library don't know why it happen,so it send a message to tell user(You) something wrong.
you can contact the author  here: https://vld.codeplex.com/discussions